# Try to replace substr with space symbol in variable

Tags: bash

I need to replace first substr that matches $d1 to $d2 value. I wrote this code:

```
i=${i/${d1}/${d2}}
```

It works well but fails if $d1 or $d2 contains space symbol. How could I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes:

```
$ i="abc def ghi"
$ d1="c d"
$ d2="C  D"
$ i="${i/${d1}/${d2}}"
$ echo "$i"
abC  Def ghi
$
```